# Sequence, dead cards with no cards to pick up

Tags: sequence

In Sequence, if you have a Dead Card and there are no other cards to pick up, can you play the dead card on your turn, saving your other cards?

Answer (score 1):

If you have gone through the entire deck then your are supposed to shuffle the discard piles and start drawing from that deck.

From the *Table Talk* section of [the Sequence rules](https://www.jaxgames.com/sequence-game-rules/):

> When the draw deck becomes depleted during play, all discard piles are shuffled together to create a new draw deck.

Comment: There are instances where there will not be cards to play in the discard pile if the board is nearly filled.  This does not answer the question that was asked

Comment: There should never be no cards to draw in theory since you shuffle the discard if the pile is empty.

Comment: If all of the Jacks are in hand and all the available places to play upon are in hand then all cards in the discard pile are dead.

Comment: I don't think the case he is talking about is covered in the rules so there might not be an answer to his question but technically you should never have an empty draw pile.

Comment: I agree.  There should never be an empty draw pile.

Answer (score 0):

From the Sequence rules at JAX Games - https://www.jaxgames.com/sequence-game-rules/

"each player selects a card of their choice from their hand and places it face up on a discard pile ... and then places one of their marker chips on the matching card on the game board."

So one cannot play a dead card since they need to place a marker chip on the board.

Comment: You missed this part of the linked page: Dead Card

If you hold a card in your hand which does not have an open space on the game board because both spaces representing that card are covered by a marker chip, you are holding a DEAD CARD and you may turn it in for a new card. When it is your turn, place the dead card on your discard pile, announce that you are turning in a Dead Card and take a replacement card (one card per turn). You then proceed to play your normal turn.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 That part is not relevant.  The question says that there are no suitable cards to replace the dead card with.  The question wants to play a dead card instead.  This answers that question accurately.  This strategy would play around Jack removal and force an opponent to play a potential card that would create a more beneficial play.

Comment: The question does **not** say "there are no suitable cards to replace the dead card with." But on further inspection, it seems like she is asking if you can use your turn by "playing" (which doesn't make sense) a dead card. So your answer is correct. Whether or not you have used your once-per-turn option to discard and redraw a dead card, you can never "play" a dead card.